# Platform Invoke for Newland barcode scanner

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, barcode-scanner

I am attempting to access a Newlands scanner using Platform Invoke from a c# program.
It should be relatively straight forward.
I set up my P/Invoke and and call it.

```
[DllImport("NLcpfw.dll", EntryPoint = "cpfw_open", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr cpfw_open(string pwStrPort,
                                                     string pwStrParam,
                                                     int nMode);

public static void CallFromHere(){
            IntPtr hDev = cpfw_open("udp", "", CPFW_OM_NORMAL);
            //GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(HNLCPFW, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(hDev != null);
            NewlandInterface.cpfw_close(hDev);

    }
```

Some how it is not picking it up.
I get a BadImageFormatException was unhandled
Make sure it is a valid managed assembly
Make sure you have supplied a correct path for the assembly

The C++ header reads

```
__declspec(dllimport) HNLCPFW WINAPI cpfw_open(WCHAR *pwStrPort, WCHAR *pwStrParam, int nMode = CPFW_OM_NORMAL);


typedef struct
{
    void* hDev;
    int nMode;
    PNLCPFW_PLUG_API DevAPI;
    HINSTANCE hPlugDll;
    void *exData;
}NLCPFW,*HNLCPFW;
```

I'm assuming it is ok just to take a IntPtr  in my p\Invoke code.

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be much appreciated.
I have copied all of the dll's in with the exe. In this case these are
NLcpfw.dll, cpfw_udp.dll, cpfw_tcp.dll,cpfw_hidpos.dll etc

Thanks leppie I need to change the platform to X86

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` implies you are compiling for the wrong bitness.

Comment: Fixed by changing platform to x86

Comment: Post your solution as the answer then (rep for you).

Comment: @JosephShanahan where did you get the information for the API?